# 3d character array problem in C

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

Im trying to make a 3d character array for the following combination of variable:  a list that can hold 10000 items that have 500 descriptors that can be 30 characters long.  The descriptors are attached individually to each item. I tried setting it up like:
char cat[10000][500][30];  but it keeps saying segmentation fault when i run it...  Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack has overflowed

The stack is used for local variables, it's not very large (typically 1Mb) - you are trying to store, 10,000 * 500 * 30 = 150Mb

Take a look at malloc()

Comment: thanks, At the time, I really wanted to stay away from malloc since I had just started learning it and was not very familiar with it.  I ended up lowering the constraints significantly to adjust for the memory issue.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that the problem is related to the fact that you're trying to declare a *150 megabyte* array. Is this thing going to be filled? Will there be precisely 10000 items each with exactly 500 descriptors, each of which is no less than 30 characters long? If the answer to any of these questions is no, then you probably do not need to allocate the full 150 megabytes in advance.

Just to get it working, you can use `malloc` instead. What is this thing actually going to be used for?

Comment: "Just to get it working" I would use `static` and see if that helps (though it possibly won't.)